# WCF 4.0 Restful URl

Tags: wcf, rest

How can i be able to have the apikey on a wcf 4.0 restful service based on the [ron jacobs tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4.aspx) to be in the following format

```
Example /customer/{apikey}/{other or no parameter}

Currently am only able to achieve the following /customer?apikey=8484734739-43948&parm2=ui
```

Comment: Why do you want to put the APIKey in the path?  In reality the API key shouldn't be in the URI at all, it should be in the authorization header.

Comment: Ok how can i achieve this  i.e apikey in the authorization header

Comment: lafama:  Set the auth header to something like `myauthscheme: 8484734739-43948` on the client and read it out on the server.  Make sure all automatic server side auth is turned off.

Comment: Please provide an example/ code of how i can set the header from the client before submitting the call to the server

Comment: lafama: Using which client library?  HttpClient or HttpWebRequest?

Comment: i was thinking more of jquery.. is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Warning:  I don't do Jquery, I copied this off some random web site and changed it a bit.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "myapikey 8484734739-43948")}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply for reference:

To append the api key to all requests, use the following code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  data: {
    apiKey: '8484734739-43948'
    ,parm2: 'ui'
  }
});
```